# How can I implement an IConfigurationProvider which loads config values from a database (on-demand)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a IConfigurationProvider (and IConfigurationSource) for ASP.NET Core 2.1 which will retrieve configuration data from a database.

I've looked a few examples (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814420.aspx, https://github.com/wintoncode/Winton.Extensions.Configuration.Consul/blob/master/src/Winton.Extensions.Configuration.Consul/ConsulConfigurationProvider.cs) but these seem to load the configuration 'up-front'. I.e. they load all configuration into memory, before any config values are requested.

I'm trying to figure out how to query the configuration database 'on-demand' for example, when Configuraiton.GetValues("xxx") is called.

My Program.cs class looks like this

```
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddDatabase("connectionString")
            .Build();

        var key = config.AsEnumerable();

        return WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
```

The issue seems to be with the UseConfiguration extension method, which just enumerates the configuration collection and adds the values at that point in time.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseConfiguration(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, IConfiguration configuration)
{
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in configuration.AsEnumerable())
    hostBuilder.UseSetting(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
  return hostBuilder;
}
```

Is there any way to defer loading the configuration until values are requested by the Startup.cs class for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it turns out I should be using the ConfigureAppConfiguration extension method, i.e.

```
        return WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((b, c) => c.AddDatabase("connectionString")))
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```